# Find $a_{n,i,j}$ in the expansion $(x + D)^n = \sum\limits_{i,j} a_{n,i,j} x^i D^j.$

Tags: generating-functions, differential-operators

This is problem 47c. in Stanley's *Enumerative Combinatorics Vol. 1*.

**Background**:
Let $D$ be the operator $\frac{d}{dx}$.  Part (a) asks to prove $$ (xD)^n = \sum\limits_{k = 0}^n S(n,k)x^k D^k $$

where $S(n,k)$ is the Stirling Number of the Second Kind.  This is quite doable by induction since we can show that the coefficients of $x^k D^k$ satisfy the same recurrence relation as the Stirling Numbers of the second kind.  Part (b) asks to prove $$ x^n D^n = xD(xD - 1)(xD - 2) \cdots (xD - n+1) = \sum\limits_{k = 0}^n s(n,k) (xD)^k, $$
where $s(n,k)$ are the Stirling Numbers of the first kind.  Again, using induction, we can show that the coefficients are indeed the Stirling Numbers of the first kind.  We then use the generating function for these Stirling Numbers to prove the $xD(xD - 1)\cdots (xD - n + 1)$ part.

---

**The Problem**: Now, part (c)---the part I'm stuck on---asks to find the coefficients $a_{n,i,j}$ in the expansion

$$ (x + D)^n = \sum\limits_{i,j} a_{n,i,j} x^i D^j. $$

---

**My Progress Thus Far**: By applying the operator $(x + D)$ to the right hand side, we see that the $a_{n,i,j}$ satisfy the recurrence relation: $$a_{n+1,i,j} = (j + 1)a_{n,i,j+1} + a_{n,i-1,j} + a_{n,i,j-1}.$$

It would be great if someone (magically) recognized this recurrence relation for some kind of triply-indexed family of integers, but that may be wishful thinking.  For $n = 4$, the coefficients look like $$ \left(\begin{array}{ccccc} 3 & 0 & 6 & 0 & 1 \\
0 & 12 & 0 & 4 & 0 \\
6 & 0 & 6 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 4 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0\end{array} \right). $$

I noticed that the skew-diagonals (if that's what they're called) are multiples of rows of Pascal's triangle, so it seems like the binomial coefficients might be playing a part.  Similarly, for $n = 5$, we have $$ \left(\begin{array}{cccccc} 0 & 15 & 0 & 10 & 0 & 1 \\ 
15 & 0 & 30 & 0 & 5 & 0 \\
0 & 30 & 0 & 10 & 0 & 0 \\
10 & 0 & 10 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 5 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0\end{array} \right) $$
and the same pattern of almost-binomial-coffiecents appears yet again.  To see if these matched anything, I plugged $0,15,0,10,0,1$---just reading off the first row of the $n = 5$ matrix---into OEIS, and it came up with ["Triangle read by rows: coefficients of modified Hermite polynomials"](https://oeis.org/A099174), so it appears that the Hermite polynomials might play some part.  However, pluggin in $15,0,30,0,5$---the second row of the $n = 5$ matrix---yields no hits from the OEIS.  I'm not sure what to do here, and I'm quite confused how this problem is related to combinatorics.  I'm not really sure what to tag this problem, so feel free to change the tags.  I'm completely stumped here, so any help is appreciated.

Comment: Better recursion: $\alpha_{n,i,j} = g_{n,i+j} \binom{i+j}{j} $ with $g_{n+1,r}= \left(r+1\right) g_{n,r+1} +g_{n,r-1} $.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The operator $e^{t(x+D)}$ is an exponential generating function for the sequence $(x+D)^n$. The commutator of the two operators $x$ and $D$ is given by $[x,D] = xD - Dx = -1$ and $[[x,D],x] = [[x,D],D] = 0$ so by [Baker-Campbell-Hausdorff](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Baker%E2%80%93Campbell%E2%80%93Hausdorff_formula#The_Zassenhaus_formula) we have

$$e^{(x+D)t}=e^{xt}e^{tD}e^{\frac{t^2}{2}}$$

or

$$\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{(x+D)^nt^n}{n!} = \sum_{i=0}^\infty \frac{x^it^i}{i!}\sum_{j=0}^\infty \frac{t^jD^j}{j!}\sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{t^{2k}}{2^kk!}$$

and by equating the coefficent of the $t^n$ term on both sides we get

$$(x+D)^n = \sum_{i+j+2k=n} \frac{n!}{2^ki!j!k!}x^i D^j\implies a_{n,i,j} = \frac{n!}{2^{\frac{n-i-j}{2}}i!j!\left(\frac{n-i-j}{2}\right)!}$$

if $n \equiv i+j\mod 2$ and $i+j\leq n$ and $a_{n,i,j} = 0$ otherwise.

Comment: Nice done! Vote up...

Comment: Wow, fantastically clear, concise and elegant.  I will award the bounty as soon as it lets me.

Comment: @MarcusM Thank you, it was a fun problem and it was nice to use some of my old Quantum Mechanics knowledge again (BCH and operator algebra). btw you might want to wait to accept at least until the bounty is over. That way you will have a bigger probability of getting other answers. I’m sure there is a nice combinatorial proof for this.

Comment: I hadn't thought of that; thanks for letting me know.

Comment: Elegant, instructive answer and concise description! (+1)

Comment: To make a further link with QM, we can recall that the (dimensionless) momentum operator $p$ has the position space representation $-i D$. Then $x+D=x+ip$, which up to a multiplicative factor is the lowering operator for the quantum harmonic oscillator.

Comment: @Semiclassical Very nice. Maybe one can solve this problem by some clever application of ladder techniques without invoking BCH directly. The relation with the harmonic oscillator also probably explains the connection to the Hermite polynomials as OP found since they describe the wave-function for this system.

Comment: Right. The (formal!) approach I was mulling over: Given a generic function $f(x)$, we can expand it in harmonic oscillator states (i.e. hermite polynomials and a gaussian factor) so that the the action of the lowering operator is simple to compute. From there one can hope to find some obvious meaning to the coefficients.

Answer (score 2):

**Note:** This answer is a supplement to the beautiful answer of @Winther. It's in no way an alternative, but an additional examination. OPs question which is  R.P. Stanleys problem $47c$ in [Enumerative Combinatorics Ed.02](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1107602629) and his elaboration give rise to some questions and I was curious to find some information.

We know from @Winther that due to the commutator property of the operator $(x+D)$ a special case of the [BCH Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Baker%E2%80%93Campbell%E2%80%93Hausdorff_formula) can be applied leading to 
\begin{align*}
e^{(x+D)t}=e^{xt}e^{Dt}e^{\frac{t^2}{2}}\tag{1}
\end{align*}

*Interesting aspects:*

- (1) OPs approach calculating $(x+D)^n$ iteratively for small $n$ leads to matrices with a relation to binomial coefficients in some skew diagonals . What is the connection with (1) and how could we derive a solution based upon OPs approach?
- (2)  Since R.P. Stanleys problems $47a$ and $47b$ are closed related to the current one and they show identities with Stirling numbers $s(n,k)$ of the first kind and Stirling numbers $S(n,k)$ of the second kind   we should expect, that $47c$ is also related to Stirling numbers.
- (3) The first row of OPs matrix for $n=5$ OPs indicates a relation to *[Hermite polynomial](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hermite_polynomials)*. How do they interact?

> **Aspect (1)** OPs matrices and **Bessel numbers**
>
> We introduce for convenience only the following shorthand notation
>
> \begin{align*}
> (x+D^\ast)^n:=\sum_{k=0}^n\binom{n}{k}x^{n-k}D^k
> \end{align*}

*Note:* This is *not* an operator in the common sense, since we don't have e.g. $(x+D^\ast)^{n+1}=(x+D^\ast)(x+D^\ast)^{n}$.

> Setting $n=4$ and $n=5$ we obtain a representation of $(x+D)^n$ as sum of binomial expressions of the form $(x+D^\ast)^k$
>
> \begin{align*}
> (x+D)^4&=x^4+4x^3D+6x^2D^2+4xD^3+D^4\\
> &\qquad+6(x^2+2xD+D^2)+3\\
> &=\color{blue}{\mathbf{1}}(x+D^\ast)^4+\color{blue}{\mathbf{6}}(x+D^\ast)^2+\color{blue}{\mathbf{3}}
> \\
> \\
> (x+D)^5&=x^5+5x^4D+10x^3D^2+10x^2D^3+5xD^4+D^5\\
> &\qquad+10(x^3+3x^2D+3xD^2+D^3)+15(x+D)\\
> &=\color{blue}{\mathbf{1}}(x+D^\ast)^5+\color{blue}{\mathbf{10}}(x+D^\ast)^3+\color{blue}{\mathbf{15}}(x+D^\ast)
> \end{align*}

This representation shows the binomial coefficients and the multiples we can see in the diagonals of OPs matrices. We focus on the coefficients of $(x+D^\ast)^k$ and find

> \begin{align*}
> \begin{array}{rrrrrrrrrr}
> &k&0&1&2&3&4&5&6&7\\\hline
> n&&\phantom{105}&\phantom{105}&\phantom{105}&\phantom{105}
> &\phantom{105}&\phantom{105}&\phantom{105}&\phantom{105}\\
> 0&&1\\
> 1&&&1\\
> 2&&&1&1\\
> 3&&&&3&1\\
> 4&&&&\color{blue}{\mathbf{3}}&\color{blue}{\mathbf{6}}&\color{blue}{\mathbf{1}}\\
> 5&&&&&\color{blue}{\mathbf{15}}&\color{blue}{\mathbf{10}}&\color{blue}{\mathbf{1}}\\
> 6&&&&&15&45&15&1\\
> 7&&&&&&105&105&21&1\\
> \end{array}
> \end{align*}
>
> The blue entries show the coefficients of the calculation above. Now OEIS identifies these entries as sequence *[A100861](https://oeis.org/A100861)*: Triangle of **Bessel numbers** read by rows.

The following information is based upon *[The Bessel numbers and matrices](http://jmre.dlut.edu.cn/cn/ch/reader/create_pdf.aspx?file_no=20110406%5C&flag=1%5C&journal_id=cn%5C&year_id=2011)* by *Sheng Liang Yang* and *Zhan Ke Qiao* and

> Bessel numbers are related to Stirling Numbers of the Second kind, since:
>
> - Bessel numbers $B(n,k)$ are the number of partitions of an $n$-set into $k$ non empty subsets, each of size at most $2$.
> - Stirling numbers of the second kind $S(n,k)$ are the number of partitions of an $n$-set into $k$ non empty subsets.
>
> The connection can also nicely be seen via the *vertical exponential generating functions* for $B(n,k)$ and $S(n,k)$
>
> \begin{align*}
> \sum_{n=k}^{\infty}B(n,k)\frac{t^n}{n!}&=\frac{1}{k!}\left(t+\frac{t^2}{2}\right)^k\tag{2}\\
> \\
> \sum_{n=k}^{\infty}S(n,k)\frac{t^n}{n!}&=\frac{1}{k!}\left(e^t-1\right)^k\\
> &=\frac{1}{k!}\left(t+\frac{t^2}{2!}+\frac{t^3}{3!}+\ldots\right)^k
> \end{align*}
>
> The number of summands in the right hand side of (2) indicates the restriction of the size of the $k$ subsets by at most $2$.

We now obtain a representation of $(x+D)^n$ with Bessel numbers:

\begin{align*}
(x+D)^n&=B(n,n)(x+D^\ast)^n+B(n,n-1)(x+D^\ast)^{n-1}\\
&\qquad+\ldots
+B(n,n-\left\lfloor\frac{n}{2}\right\rfloor)(x+D^\ast)^{n-2\left\lfloor\frac{n}{2}\right\rfloor}\\
&=\sum_{k=0}^{\lfloor\frac{n}{2}\rfloor}B(n,n-k)(x+D^\ast)^{n-2k}\\%\tag{3}\\
&=\sum_{k=0}^{\lfloor\frac{n}{2}\rfloor}B(n,n-k)\sum_{l=0}^{n-2l}\binom{n-2k}{l}x^lD^{n-2k-l}\\
\end{align*}

The coefficients of $(x+D)^n=\sum_{i,j}a_{n,i,j}x^iD^j$ are in terms of Bessel numbers

\begin{align*}
a_{n,i,j}&=[x^iD^j](x+D)^n\\
&=[D^j]\sum_{k=0}^{\lfloor\frac{n}{2}\rfloor}B(n,n-k)\sum_{l=0}^{n-2l}\binom{n-2k}{i}D^{n-2k-i}\\
&=\begin{cases}
{\displaystyle B(n,\frac{n+i+j}{2})\binom{i+j}{i}}&\qquad\qquad i+j\equiv n(2)
\\
0&\qquad\qquad \text{otherwise}
\end{cases}
\end{align*}
In the last line we use $n-2k-i=j$, so $k=\frac{n-i-j}{2}$ if $i+j\equiv n(2)$

> *Connection with $e^{xt}e^{Dt}e^{\frac{t^2}{2}}$*:
>
> Using (1) we obtain following representation of $B(n,k)$.
>
> \begin{align*}
> e^{xt}e^{Dt}e^{\frac{t^2}{2}}&=\sum_{i\geq 0}\frac{x^i}{i!}t^i \sum_{j\geq 0}\frac{D^j}{j!}t^je^{\frac{t^2}{2}}\\
> &=\sum_{i\geq 0}\sum_{j\geq 0}\binom{i+j}{i}x^iD^j\frac{t^{i+j}}{(i+j)!}\sum_{k\geq 0}\frac{1}{2^k}\frac{t^{2k}}{k!}\\
> &=\sum_{n\geq 0}\sum_{{i,j,k\geq 0}\atop{i+j+2k=n}}\binom{i+j}{i}\frac{1}{(i+j)!}\frac{1}{k!}\frac{1}{2^k}x^iD^jt^{i+j+2k}\\
> &=\sum_{n\geq 0}\sum_{{0\leq i,j\leq n}\atop{i+j\equiv n(2)}}\binom{i+j}{i}\frac{n!}{(i+j)!\left(\frac{n-i-j}{2}\right)!}\cdot\frac{1}{2^{\frac{n-i-j}{2}}}x^iD^j\frac{t^{n}}{n!}\\
> \end{align*}
>
> We conclude
>
> \begin{align*}
> B\left(n,\frac{n+i+j}{2}\right)=
> \begin{cases}
> {\displaystyle
> \frac{n!}{(i+j)!\left(\frac{n-i-j}{2}\right)!}\cdot\frac{1}{2^{\frac{n-i-j}{2}}}
> }&\qquad\qquad i+j\equiv n(2)\\
> 0&\qquad\qquad \text{otherwise}
> \end{cases}
> \end{align*}
>
> Of course, we could also derive a closed formula for $B(n,k)$ with other means, e.g. the representation of (2).

$$$$

> **Aspect (2)** Connection with Stirling numbers
>
> A well known relationship between Stirling numbers of the first kind and of the second kind is
>   \begin{align*}
> \sum_{j=0}^ns(n,j)S(j,k)=\delta_{n,k}\qquad n\geq 0, \quad 0\leq k \leq n
> \end{align*}
>   with $\delta_{n,k}$ the *[Kronecker delta](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kronecker_delta)* symbol. The authors use exponential *[Riordan arrays](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riordan_array)* in their paper to show in (19) a similar identity with Bessel numbers.
>
> \begin{align*}
> B(n,k)=\sum_{j=k}^n2^{j-k}s(n,j)S(j,k)\qquad n\geq 0, \quad 0\leq k \leq n
> \end{align*}

$$$$

> **Aspect (3)** Connection with Hermite Polynomials
>
> We can also find information regarding Hermite Polynomials in the paper. The sequence of row sums of the table with the Bessel numbers above can according to Theorem 3.2 be represented by Hermite polynomials,
>   \begin{align*}
> H_n(x)=\sum_{k=0}^{\left\lfloor\frac{n}{2}\right\rfloor}\frac{(-1)^kn!}{k!(n-2k)!}(2x)^{n-2k}
> \end{align*}
>
> which can be defined by the generating function
>   \begin{align*}
> \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}H_n(x)\frac{t^n}{n!}=e^{2xt-t^2}
> \end{align*}
>   The shape of this generating function makes a connection with the generating functions of the Bessel numbers plausible. In fact, the Hermite functions play an important role when studying differentiation operators. See e.g.  *[Generalized polynomials, operational identities and their applications](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0377042700002831)* by G. Dattoli. He presents with formula (18) the following generalisation of $(x+D)^n$ in terms of Hermite polynomials:
>   \begin{align*}
> (\alpha D+\beta x)^n=\sum_{k=0}^n\binom{n}{k}\alpha^kH_{n-k}\left(\beta x,\frac{1}{2}\alpha\beta\right)D^k
> \end{align*}