# Ladder Operations and Rodriguez formula

Tags: derivatives, operator-theory, hermite-polynomials

During my attempt to prove the Rodriguez Formula for Hermite Polynomials by using the Ladder Operators,
$H_n(x) = (-1)^n e^{x^2}\frac{d^n}{dx^n}e^{-x^2}$, I arrived to the formula $H_n(x) =  e^{x^2/2}(-\frac{d}{dx}+x)^ne^{-x^2/2}$.Where $(-\frac{d}{dx}+x)^n$ represents the operator being applied n times. Now I have no idea on how to prove these two to be equivalent. Any hints or solutions would be appreciated

Comment: You can prove it by induction

Comment: How did you define the polynomials? If at this point you already have the [recurrence relation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hermite_polynomials#Recurrence_relation), you can just verify that Rodriguez's formula satisfies the recurrence.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

$\textbf{Hint}:$ Notice that $e^{x^2/2} = e^{x^2}e^{-x^2/2}$ and

$$\left[e^{-x^2/2},\left(-\frac{d}{dx}+x\right)\right] = -xe^{-x^2/2}$$

Comment: [+1] Interesting connection with [this question/answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1841868/305862)

Answer (score 3):

This is *completely* equivalent to @Ninad Munshi 's fine operatorial calculus identity, so then
$$
e^{x^2} \partial_x e^{-x^2}=e^{x^2/2} (\partial_x -x) e^{-x^2/2}~~~\implies \\ (e^{x^2} \partial_x e^{-x^2})^n =(e^{x^2/2} (\partial_x -x) e^{-x^2/2})^n.
$$
Multiplying on the right  by 1 to terminate further action of the derivatives, you just recover $(-)^n H_n(x)$. I suspect that conversion was at the root of your puzzlement. In fact, WP has the shorter reduced form,
$$
H_n(x) = \left(2x -  \partial_x \right)^n \cdot 1
$$